# Создание НС, определяющей исправность/неисправность ограждений

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, google-colaboratory

Подскажите на какие основные моменты обратить при создании нейронной сети, определяющей исправность/неисправность ограждений. Использовал для создания google colaborator, создал 2 датасета, однако с датасетом с неисправными ограждениями возникли трудности в отсутствии изображений в интернете (создавал сам, потому что не нашёл готовых).
Возникали так же проблемы с загрузкой датасета в колаб.
Если есть у какие советы, то прошу подсказать пожалуйста.